# How to set the due date of Trello cards to weekends?

Tags: trello

I'm using Trello board as project management, but when I set the card due date as a weekend, it automatically change to the nearest working day. Fore example, if I would like to set a project card due date as 8/18/2019 (Sunday), Trello auto change to 8/16/2019 (Friday). How can I set up this?

Really frustrated, please help.

Comment: do you have some other powerup/extension/addon for trello? I've got lots of due dates set on weekends and this never happens to me

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response, Bigpicture is the only power up that i installed... will this prevent setting the dates?

Comment: @duffj I've never used that power up, but considering that its a project management addon, it just might be doing that. I would recommend trying disabling the powerup or try checking in with their support

Comment: I have the same problem. I don't have any powerups installed and it happens to me too. Have you found a solution yet?